# How can I filter the Excel column by dates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pywin32

The bottom line is that the column contains data in the form of m/dd/yyyy and the data type is Date, as a result of which Excel screws up the filtering * first select the year, for example, 2023, and then the month, for example March*, after which we save the file and exit so that for the user who opens the file, he has already been filtered this way
In general, through COM I found a way to filter by string values, but here's how to do it by dates - so far I have no idea

Here is the solution with the usual string values

```
import win32com.client as win32

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open('file.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.Worksheets('Sheet1')

# Find column
date_column = worksheet.Rows(1).Find("column with text data").Column

# Filter on column
worksheet.Range('A1').AutoFilter(Field=date_column, Criteria1='Hello123')

# Save and quit
workbook.Save()
excel.Application.Quit()
```

this is how I tried to work with dates

```
import win32com.client as win32

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open('file.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.Worksheets('Sheet1')

# Find column "Date"
date_column = worksheet.Rows(1).Find("Date").Column

# Filter on column
worksheet.Range('A1').AutoFilter(Field=date_column, Criteria1='2023')
worksheet.Range('A1').AutoFilter(Field=date_column, Criteria1='March')

# Save and Quit
workbook.Save()
excel.Application.Quit()
```

import win32com.client as win32

```
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open('file.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.Worksheets('Sheet1')

date_column = worksheet.Rows(1).Find("Date").Column

worksheet.Columns(date_column).AutoFilter(Operator=14, Criteria2="2023")
worksheet.Columns(date_column).AutoFilter(Operator=11, Criteria1="March")

workbook.Save()
excel.Application.Quit()
```

```
import win32com.client as win32

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open('file.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.Worksheets('Sheet1')

date_column = worksheet.Rows(1).Find("Date").Column

worksheet.Columns(date_column).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"

worksheet.Columns(date_column).AutoFilter(Operator=14, Criteria2="2023")
worksheet.Columns(date_column).AutoFilter(Operator=11, Criteria1="March")

workbook.Save()
excel.Application.Quit()
```

```
import win32com.client as win32
import datetime

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open('file.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.Worksheets('Sheet1')

date_column = worksheet.Rows(1).Find("Date").Column

date_filter = datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

worksheet.Range('A1').AutoFilter(Field=date_column, Criteria1=date_filter, Operator=7)

workbook.Save()
excel.Application.Quit()
```

all the methods above did not help me

Answer (score 0):

For the AutoFormat function the Field value is the integer offset on the range where it is applied.
In this case worksheet.columns(date_column) is only one column.
So the Field value is 1.
The Criteria must be string and exactly match with the item you filter.